# Juju bootstrap environment fails

Tags: juju, maas, curl, environment

i have a problem during deploying my first juju environment "maas".
The host is commissioned by MAAS but during the juju deployment there is this error:

```
Setting up libtcmalloc-minimal4 (2.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgoogle-perftools4 (2.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsnappy1 (1.1.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up juju-mongodb (2.4.9-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.1) ...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable tools from http://172.19.202.71/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=0b492b0c-2ce4-11e4-9494-525400f28eaf&op=get_by_key
downloaded: HTTP 503; time 74.994s; size 0 bytes; speed 0.000 bytes/s
2014-08-26 06:00:43 ERROR juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:123 bootstrap
failed: rc: 1
Stopping instance...
2014-08-26 06:00:43 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:113 Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
2014-08-26 06:00:43 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:14 destroying environment "maas"
2014-08-26 06:00:44 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:300 rc: 1
```

i use Ubuntu 14.04 in a KVM environment.

my environments.yaml looks like:

```
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://172.19.202.71/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: 'ZJ9GLGqSVSWdZ6eXET:AjCdJRwgS26jsBwHp8:gpwhCLf6P2AJCh3mcGL2vRqhbSvkwRGB'
    admin-secret: 'MY-PASSWORD'
    default-series: trusty
    http-proxy: http://172.19.202.70:8000
    https-proxy: https://172.19.202.70:8000
    no-proxy: localhost,172.19.202.0/24
    bootstrap-timeout: 1800
```

does someone know this problem?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Your `no-proxy` setting has incorrect format. It should be a comma-delimited list of IP addresses, not a CIDR range. Take a look at this related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/set-a-network-range-in-the-no-proxy-environment-variable

I'd recommend you set `no-proxy: 127.0.0.1,172.19.202.71` instead and try again.
If it does not work, please update the question and maybe file a bug against juju-core: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core